# ACL permissions on Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: permissions, acl

Hi as the owner of a file and directory I allowed the user TOM to have read permissions to the file :

```
owner@hostname:~$ getfacl file1
 user::rw-
 user::tom:r--
 group::rw-
 mask::rw-
 other::r--
```

and I gave the user TOM default permissions to read and execute into the directory of that file:

```
owner@hostname:~$ getfacl /home/owner/docs/
 user::rwx
 group::rwx
 other::r-x
 default:user::rwx
 default:user:tom:r-x
 default:group::rwx
 default:mask::rwx
 default:other::r-x
```

But when I use TOM to try and move into the directory I get denied:

```
tom@hostname:~$ cd /home/owner/docs
 -bash: cd: /home/owner/docs/:Permission denied
```

The permissions for the owner are as follows:

```
owner@hostname:~$ namei -mo /home/owner/docs
 f: /home/owner/docs/
  drwxr-xr-x root root /
  drwxr-xr-x root root home
  drwx------ owner owner owner
  drwxrwxr-x owner owner docs
```

Can anyone help me set this right? Thank you.

Comment: What about execute permissions of `/home/owner`? Please add the output of `namei -mo /home/owner/docs`.

Comment: Sorry about that I just added the permissions of /home/owner @muru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, `/home/owner` has absolutely no permissions for any other user. At least give execute permissions so that other users can traverse it to reach subdirectories within:

```
chmod o+x /home/owner
```

Comment: I tried the above command while using OWNER : `chmod o+x /home/owner/` but I'm still getting Permission denied when I try to access the file through the directory with TOM.  Is the only way to fix this to set the permissions using root?

Comment: @thankgodforthissite you still can't `cd` to that directory using `tom`?

Comment: Nope.  I tried to do it thru root, and I just found out that the directory for OWNER is encrypted.  Could that be the problem? Well...that has to be the problem, if root can't access it then TOM won't be able to. Right? @muru

Comment: @thankgodforthissite yes, but you are working with the unencrypted contents, right? Hasn't OWNER logged in?

Comment: Oh wow... I was logged in as TOM and then I would do: `su owner` to try to fix it then log off of OWNER.  But with OWNER logged in, it worked.  Thanks again, appreciate it. @muru