# Granting permissions for a folder in user area

Tags: permissions

(Ubuntu Server 14.04.2)

Lets say I have two user accounts with the usernames **alex** and **bob** - where alex has superuser privilages.

Within **alex's** home directory, he has lots of directories which **bob** cannot access. **alex** wants to give **bob** permissions to just one directory within his home area where **bob** can  upload, read, edit and delete files in there, but the rest of his home area **bob** should not have access. Let's say the folder is `/home/alex/bob_folder_access`.

How can **alex** grant these exact permissions?

Comment: I think http://askubuntu.com/questions/605134/acl-permissions-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-2-lts might assist you with some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add alex and bob to some group, and execute

```
chgrp -R somegroup /home/alex/bob_folder_access
chmod -R g+rwX /home/alex/bob_folder_access
```